# prevent from verbs form

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-structure

I know that after "prevent from" we have to use a verb with "ing". My question is when we want to use two verbs, connecting with "and" to each other, should we use the ing form of both of them or just the first one? For example:

> She was always plotting ways to prevent animals from starving and demise.

or

> She was always plotting ways to prevent animals from starving and demising.

Comment: _Demise_ is a noun, so there is no participle _demising_. We would say _starving to death_. However, in other sentences it would be usual to use two participles - _The rail is there to prevent you from falling and hurting yourself_.

Comment: @KateBunting That's worth making into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Demise* is a noun, not a verb, so we can't make a participle (a 'verb with -ing') from it. A more natural expression would be *starving to death*.

(*Plotting* usually means planning something bad, so it would be better to use *planning* or *trying to find.*)

In answer to your question about using two verbs after *prevent* - yes, you need to use two participles.

> The rail is there to prevent you from falling and hurting yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your perfect explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The important word here is "from", not "prevent".  From is a preposition and the object of the preposition could be a phrase headed by gerund like "eating too much" or a noun phrase.

Now with the meaning of "prevent" it is natural to use a word that relates to an action, and so the gerund is going to be much more common. However some nouns could work in this context "prevent him from death", for example.

Now "demise" is a noun, not a verb.  So "demising" isn't correct. Instead of "prevent him from demise" you would say "prevent his demise".

While it may be possible to combine "starving and demise" - you should realise that there might be a better way to express this.  You can rephrase to avoid the problem.

What you actually mean is "starving to death".

> She was always plotting ways to prevent animals from starving to death.

Comment: Thank you a lot.